# Sequence Notation in Analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, notation

If real sequence is a function from the set $\mathbb N$ to the set $\mathbb R$ and function is represented by $(a,b)$, where $a$ is domain and $b$ is range, then why do we represent sequence only by $\{S_1,S_2,S_3.....S_n\}$ not by $(a,b)$ form?

Comment: umm because $a=\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: if the map is $f:{\Bbb{N}}\to{\Bbb{R}}$ and $f(a)=b$, then this is equivalent to day $(a,b)\in f$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question already contains the answer: since the domain is fixed (i.e. $\mathbb N$), the only useful information about a sequence is provided by the range and its action.

However, don't forget that a generic function consists of *three* pieces: the domain, the codomain, and the law that associates an element from the domain to a unique element of the range.

Comment: thankyou, your answer is very simple and straight.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of reason domain is fixed. So we prefer to write as $\langle S_1,S_2,S_3, \ldots, S_n \rangle$.
In fact note also it is given in many books notation $\{S_1,S_2,S_3, \ldots, S_n\}$. But it is misleading in two ways:

$1$. As you mentioned why we don't have $(a,b)$ inside it. But in books where this notation is used, there clarify this in beginning.

$2$. In case of constant sequence $\{1,1,1,1, \ldots\}$ you may confuse this as set and then write $\{1\}$ but then there is no sequence left.

Hence its better to write like $\langle S_1,S_2,S_3, \ldots, S_n \rangle$ and leave $\{S_1,S_2,S_3, \ldots S_n\}$ notation for range or set of terms of sequence

Answer (score 0):

If $S:{\Bbb{N}}\to{\Bbb{R}}$ is the function that assigns $n\mapsto S(n)$, then $S_n$ is an abbreviation of $S(n)$.

Seen as a pair the notation is $(n,S_n)$.